# Set the color of particular element on item in custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

For example I have Custom Adapter List View, and my list item is a layout that contains different elements: textview, imageView and so on. How can I set the color of imageview of selected list item? Suppose I want to add this item in favourite and I want to change the color of star favourite for yellow color. Thank you)

```
       list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), PlaceName[position] + " in favourite", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Do smth here, set the color of element on item, add to favourite and something else
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have this line:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html

According to the docs, `view` is the layout that you actually clicked, so you can get the child of that `View` using something like this:

```
ImageView favorite = view.findViewById(R.id.yourFavoriteImageView);
```

Note that if you scroll through your list, the layout might render again, and your change won't be visible again.

Answer (score 0):

view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));

Comment: In this case you will change the background color for whole item, but I need to change the color for only one element of list item